# Clarification on a binomial summation

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I need to use the following sum in a homework problem:

> $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (-1)^i {n \choose i}, 0\leq k \leq n.$

In the problem it says that the sum is equal to the following:

> $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (-1)^i {n \choose i}=(-1)^k {n-1 \choose k}.$

However, I think this is a typo since if $k=n$ we get ${n-1 \choose n}$ which does not make sense to me. Also notice that if we let $k=1$ then the formula tells us that $-n=-{n \choose 1}=-{n-1 \choose 1}=-(n-1)$.

Does anyone happen to know if there is a typo, and if so what the summation is actually equal to?

Thanks!

Comment: [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) says $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (-1)^i {n \choose i}=(-1)^k {n-1 \choose k} - 1$.

Comment: (cont'd) In other words, the sum should start with $i=0$: $\sum\limits_{i=0}^k (-1)^i {n \choose i}=(-1)^k {n-1 \choose k}$

Answer (score 0):

We define $\binom{a}{b} = 0$ if $b > a$. Combinatorially, if I have $a$ letters, a subset of size $b$ is impossible to create.

Comment: Thanks, but I still think the formula is wrong, for if $k=1$ we get that $-n=-{n \choose 1}=-{n-1 \choose 1}=-(n-1)$. Which is false. I know that this is not the original reason I thought there was a typo, but I will now edit my question to include this reasoning as well.

Answer (score 0):

My Professor got back to me and provided me with the following fix:

> $\sum\limits_{i=0}^k (-1)^i {n \choose i} = (-1)^k {n-1 \choose k}, \ 1\leq k\leq n$.

Now the correct version of the equation will be here for anybody that may need it.